# Mac application compatibility (Snow Leopard/Lion)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am developing a Mac app (using Xcode 4.2). My observation during testing is that its working properly on Snow Leopard but few of the buttons/functionality is not showing the expected result on Lion.

Why is that? Do I need to upgrade the Xcode or some libraries needs to be included?
Any kind of help would be useful as I am a newbie in Mac development.

Comment: Please include more details. What exactly isn't showing/working?

Comment: You need to install Lion and test it yourself, rather than relying on your customer to test it; better still switch to Lion for development.

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe, your advice helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change deployment target. This identifies the earliest OS version on which your software can run. By default, Xcode sets this to the version of the OS corresponding to the base SDK version and later. You can change that either on the project settings summary screen or in the project settings configuration settings.
Take a look at [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html).

Comment: Thanks all for the swift response. I have tried doing that but could not find the latest version for LION OS.  Monolo, jrturton - Some of the buttons( which are saving customer details from text view are not functioning) I have built this app on Snow Leopard and my customer is testing it on a different machine with LION (he is not a techie) and I am not able to see the problem in code.UI is created in Interface Builder. Pls help.